# WordPress : Media Library broken images

Tags: wordpress, image, media-library

When I upload image to WordPress, they randomly appear as broken links.

I can drop the files on the Media Library or Select the files and some files are always shown as broken.

I can delete the files and re-upload the same group and different images in the group can show as broken.

I'm sure it's nothing to with the images as they sometimes appear as broken and then sometimes don't.

Locally the upload works fine, this problem started happening on the live hosting - I thought it could be something to do with permissions but then wouldn't it show all the images as broken and not show random images as broken.

I don't get an error but a broken image icon. If I click the broken link it case me to the Attachment Details page. Sometimes the image does appear here sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Can you attach a screen shot of the error?

Comment: There is no error as such but a broken link image where the image should be

Comment: What if you login to the FTP and go to the wp-content/uploads folder and find the images you just uploaded, open them to see if they get uploaded fully.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to look for:

1) check if there is an .htaccess file in the wp-content/uploads folder or wherever you keep your images (make sure you have the option to see hidden files--I think they're available by default when you're using an FTP client but if you're in the File Manager of your CPanel then you have to enable this option, either before entering file manager or from settings when you're in the file manager depending on your host). If there is an htaccess file, you'll want to back it up and then research more about this before you make any changes to it.  https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess_for_subdirectories

2) if you had tried to move your default image directory using wp-config.php make sure that has been set up properly

3) check folder and file permissions settings. it's best to do this in an FTP client because if you need to change the permissions, it can do it recursively and include all subdirectories and files within them instead of having to go through into each folder and change the permissions.
http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-image-upload-issue-in-wordpress/