# Images registered in Media uploads - but with empty content after Rsync

Tags: wordpress, image, upload, media, rsync

I have a problem with some of my Wordpress Media Images not loading correctly.

I recently pushed the website online from local, using db-sync and rsync to transfer the uploads folder.

The weird part is 409/421 images work correctly. So only 12 images are affected, all from the year 2017, but from different month folders and I don't see any differences between these images and the ones which load correctly.

The problem is, they **are registered in WordPress Media** and are listed there, **but the content is empty**, meaning the actual image is not shown.

[Images registered but empty content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmkxs.png)

I already tried what was recommended here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43018159/7067143

There are no .htaccess files in the uploads folder or any subfolders.
The permissions are correct.
The wp-config.php is set up correctly.

I also deactivated any caching addons, deleted the complete uploads-folder and reuploaded it again and also tried the plugins "Add From Server" and "Media from FTP" but they won't let me register the images, as they are already registered.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Thanks in advance

Max

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone every stumbles upon this post. The problem was umlauts in the image file names: ä ö ü.